# How do I separate the functions from the gui class in PySide?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

In my PySide project I have 3 files:

- one that contains all the gui stuff converted to python from Qt Designer,
- another which has the signals, all the logic and functions and
- one more that starts the whole application.

I think it's better to separate the logic from the functions.

The following is a simple function inserting items in a tablewidget:

```
# my_functions.py
def fill_table():
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(10):
         item_value = "...."
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         item.setText(str(item_value))
         table_widget.setItem(row, col, item)
```

My main problem is how would you reference a widget from your application in a separate module.

Comment: You can re-write functions into new files as per need and call them from your main script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `my_functions.py` is second item in your list of files, it appears that fill function uses a module-global `table_widget`. I don't recommend that but if that's really what you want, then just access it. So with

```
# my_functions.py
table_widget = ...  # somewhere in that file, not shown in your post
def fill_table(): 
     ...populate table_widget...
```

Then:

```
# main.py
import my_functions
...
... somewhere, use my_functions.table_widget...
```

Better would be to define a custom class in `my_functions.py`, instantiate in `main.py`, and make `fill_table()` a method on custom class:

```
# my_functions.py
class MyTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    ...
    def fill(self):
        for row in range(10):
            for col in range(10):
                item_value = "...."
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(str(item_value))
                self.setItem(row, col, item)

# main.py
from my_functions import MyTableWidget
table = MyTableWidget()
table.fill()
```

There are lots of ways, but basically it seems that your current design is procedural rather than object-oriented. Nothing wrong with that, but you will find it rather clashes with the rest of PyQt and Python after a while, and is not as easy to maintain and debug once your app passes the stage of prototyping. So I recommend second approach.

Comment: How would you reference, lets say a tablewidget in func1.py ?

Comment: Looks like you've updated your post, so I updated my answer to be more specific to your situation.

Comment: The my_functions.py is a fourth file that will include every function that now is included under the main class in my second file in my list.

Comment: It seems to me the technique in the answer still applies,  but if you don't think  so, you should edit your post to clarify and ensure all pertinent info is there.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in a typical Qt application are connected together in parent/child relationships. Most often, there is a top-level main-window which functions as the root object, with all the other objects (widgets, layouts, etc) arranged in a hierarchy below it.

Given this, it is very natural to put all the gui-related program logic in the main-window class, because all the other objects will then be accessible via `self`. But if you put all the gui-related logic into functions in separate modules, there is no `self` available. So it would be up to you to provide that missing functionality.

The most obvious way to do this would be to keep a reference to the top-level window in the module that starts the application, so that the other modules can import it:

```
from app_module import main_window

# my_functions.py
def fill_table():
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(10):
            item_value = "...."
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(item_value))
            main_window.table_widget.setItem(row, col, item)
```

Alternatively, you could re-design all the functions so that they operate on only one object (or class of objects), and then explicitly pass in an instance:

```
# my_functions.py
def fill_table(table_widget):
    ...
```

However, whatever way you do it, it's hard to see how this could ever be the "best" way to structure the code.

Most gui applications consist of several largish sub-components that work more-or-less independently of one another, along with a central controller/manager that organises them all into a single functioning unit. The sub-components will usually be widget sub-classes (probably living in separate modules), which will become children of a main-window which may also function as the controller/manager. Organising your code along these lines is much more in line with the way Qt is designed to work, and will automatically avoid most of the potential communication problems between the various parts of the application.